# Highcharts series name title not showing

Tags: highcharts

My chart was ok, I don't know what happened that the series name disappeared!

Maybe highcharts last updates need another options, or rtl causes problems.

My code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanatech/buYCZ/407/)

What am I missing here?

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.chart('user_info_46', {
            chart: {
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie',
            },
            title: {
                text: '',
                useHTML: Highcharts.hasBidiBug,
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            legend: {
                useHTML: true,
                align: 'right',
                rtl: true,
            },
            tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
                align: 'right',
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'تعداد',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'آقا',
                    y: 7,
                    color: 'cornsilk'
                }, {
                    name: 'خانم',
                    y: 2,
                    color: 'green'
                }]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ...but there is nothing in `title.text`? It's just `''`.

Comment: @HalvorStrand I think he means in the legend on bottom right. Without `useHTML: true,` the legend appear but is covered by the legend dot.

Comment: It looks like it is a bug introduced along with v6.0.0. It is already fixed on master version, so it means v6.0.2 will be free of it. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a1a67dcp/.